# Crear Client desde código para WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf, app.config

Estoy trabajando en consumir un WebService desarrollado en WCF, ya agregué la referencia, agregué al app.config la configuración para el cliente, pero quería saber sí existe alguna forma de pasar esa configuración al código, para poder guardarla en una base de datos y llamarla en tiempo de ejecución antes de ejecutar el WebService

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EndPointBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://midireccion"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointBinding"
        contract="WS.IWS" name="clientBinding" />
 </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Existe alguna forma de pasar esa configuración a Código y llamarla en  tiempo de ejecución. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: [Googleando](https://www.google.com.gt/search?site=&source=hp&q=create+endpoint+c%23+via+codigo&oq=create+endpoint+c%23+via+codigo&gs_l=hp.3..33i160k1.1157.11979.0.12522.25.23.0.2.2.0.166.2131.9j11.20.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..3.22.2132...0j0i131k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j33i21k1.PrALhAO1ZDI) un poco me encontre con esto https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080(v=vs.110).aspx espero te sirva, habla de como crear un **_endpoint_** via codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible utilizando el método `Configure`, por ejemplo:

```
public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)   
{   
    // Enable “Add Service Reference” support   
    config.Description.Behaviors.Add( new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });   
    // set up support for http, https, net.tcp, net.pipe   
    config.EnableProtocol(new BasicHttpBinding());   
    config.EnableProtocol(new BasicHttpBinding());   
    config.EnableProtocol(new NetTcpBinding());   
    config.EnableProtocol(new NetNamedPipeBinding());   
    // add an extra BasicHttpBinding endpoint at http:///basic   
    config.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(),"basic");   
}
```

Código de ejemplo extraído directamente desde la página de la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277(v=vs.110).aspx).